# I can not use two conditions in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form>

<input type="radio" name="adsType" id="adsType" value="request" />
<input type="radio" name="adsType" id="adsType" value="provide" />

<select name="transactionType" id="transactionType">
    <option value="1">Sale</option>
    <option value="2">Rent</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
<input type="text" name="min_price" id="price" />
<input type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price" />


<input type="text" name="fare" id="fare" />
<input type="text" name="min_fare" id="min_fare" />
<input type="text" name="max_fare" id="max_fare" />

</form>
```

I want:

when `provide` selected and click on `Sale` display `price` input only,

when `provide` selected and click on `Rent` display `fare` input only,

when `request` selected and click on `Sale` display `min_price` and `max_price` inputs,

when `request` selected and click on `Rent` display `min_fare` and `max_fare` inputs

i am trying for this javascript:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
$('input[name=adsType]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'provide') {

        $('select[name=transactionType]').change(function () {


                if ($(this).val() == '1') { /* Provide type | Sale type => display 'price' input only */
                    $('#price').show();
                } else {
                    $('#price').hide();
                }

                if ($(this).val() == '2') { /* Provide type | Rent type => display 'fare' input only */
                    $('#fare').show();
                } else {
                    $('#fare').hide();
                }

            });
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'request') {
        if ($(this).val() == '1') { /* Request type | Sale type => display 'min_price' and 'max_price' inputs */
            $('#min_price').show();
            $('#max_price').show();
        } else {
            $('#min_price').hide();
            $('#max_price').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).val() == '2') { /* Request type | Rent type => display 'min_fare' and 'max_fare' inputs */
            $('#min_fare').show();
            $('#max_fare').show();
        } else {
            $('#min_fare').hide();
            $('#max_fare').hide();
        }

        });
    }
});

});//]]>
```

But it not return good result. Please help me to edit this JavaScript code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this may help. See the snippet and comments in the code:

```js
$(function() {

  function toggleFields() {

    // setup which fields to show in every case
    var items = {
      provide: {
        1: '#price',
        2: '#fare'
      },
      request: {
        1: '#min_price, #max_price',
        2: '#min_fare, #max_fare'
      }
    }

    // get the selected values
    var ad = $('input[name="adsType"]:checked').val(),
        tr = $('select[name="transactionType"]').val();

    // hide all and show required
    $('[id*="price"], [id*="fare"]').hide();
    $(items[ad][tr]).show();

  }

  // handler for changes
  $('select[name="transactionType"], input[name="adsType"]').change(toggleFields);
  
  // initial run
  toggleFields();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  <label>request <input type="radio" name="adsType" value="request" checked/></label>
  <label>provide <input type="radio" name="adsType" value="provide" /></label>

  <select name="transactionType" id="transactionType">
    <option value="1" selected>Sale</option>
    <option value="2">Rent</option>
  </select>

  <div>
    <label id="price">price <input type="text" name="price" /></label>
    <label id="min_price">min_price <input type="text" name="min_price" /></label>
    <label id="max_price">max_price <input type="text" name="max_price" /></label>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label id="fare">fare <input type="text" name="fare" /></label>
    <label id="min_fare">min_fare <input type="text" name="min_fare" /></label>
    <label id="max_fare">max_fare <input type="text" name="max_fare" /></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY IT:

```
         $(document).ready(function () {

                var radioValue = "request";
                var transactionValue = 1;

                $('input[name=adsType]').change(function () {


                    radioValue = $(this).val();
                    update();

                });

                $('select[name=transactionType]').change(function () {


                    transactionValue = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);


                    update();

                });


                function update() {


                    if (radioValue === "provide") {
                        if (transactionValue === 1) {
                            $('#price').show();
                            $('#min_price').hide();
                            $('#max_price').hide();
                            $('#fare').hide();
                            $('#min_fare').hide();
                            $('#max_fare').hide();
                        } else {
                            $('#price').hide();
                            $('#min_price').hide();
                            $('#max_price').hide();
                            $('#fare').show();
                            $('#min_fare').hide();
                            $('#max_fare').hide();
                        }

                    } else {
                        if (transactionValue === 1) {
                            $('#price').hide();
                            $('#min_price').show();
                            $('#max_price').show();
                            $('#fare').hide();
                            $('#min_fare').hide();
                            $('#max_fare').hide();
                        } else {
                            $('#price').hide();
                            $('#min_price').hide();
                            $('#max_price').hide();
                            $('#fare').hide();
                            $('#min_fare').show();
                            $('#max_fare').show();
                        }


                    }




                }

                update();
            });
```

FORM HTML > Please check form id: min_price

```
    <form>

            <input type="radio" name="adsType" id="adsType" value="request" checked="checked" />
            <input type="radio" name="adsType" id="adsType" value="provide" />

            <select name="transactionType" id="transactionType">
                <option value="1" selected="selected">Sale</option>
                <option value="2">Rent</option>
            </select>

            <input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
            <input type="text" name="min_price" id="min_price" />
            <input type="text" name="max_price" id="max_price" />


            <input type="text" name="fare" id="fare" />
            <input type="text" name="min_fare" id="min_fare" />
            <input type="text" name="max_fare" id="max_fare" />

        </form>
```

Comment: you should explain why your code works and why the OP's doesn't.

Comment: your code are binding $('select[name=transactionType]').change() all time that value change. you should bind the event  only 1 time. And you show but not hide others.

Answer (score 1):

There is no onchange event for the select box inside the  `if ($(this).val() == 'request') {` of your code.

I have made some changes like adding class `all` to the inputs `#price #fare #max_price #max_fare #min_price #min_fare`.

You can go through the code in the below snippet.

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
  $('input[name=adsType]').change(function() {
  $('.all').hide();
  $('#transactionType').val('');
    if ($(this).val() == 'provide') {
      
      $('select[name=transactionType]').change(function() {

$('.all').hide();
        if ($(this).val() == '1') { /* Provide type | Sale type => display 'price' input only */
          $('#price').show();
        }

        if ($(this).val() == '2') { /* Provide type | Rent type => display 'fare' input only */
          $('#fare').show();
        }

      });
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 'request') {
    $('select[name=transactionType]').change(function() {
      $('.all').hide();
      if ($(this).val() == '1') { /* Request type | Sale type => display 'min_price' and 'max_price' inputs */
        $('#min_price, #max_price').show();
      }

      if ($(this).val() == '2') { /* Request type | Rent type => display 'min_fare' and 'max_fare' inputs */
        $('#min_fare, #max_fare').show();
      }
});
    };
  });

});
```

```css
.all {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>

  request<input type="radio" name="adsType" id="adsType" value="request" /> provide
  <input type="radio" name="adsType" id="adsType" value="provide" />

  <select name="transactionType" id="transactionType">
    <option value="" selected></option>
    <option value="1">Sale</option>
    <option value="2">Rent</option>
</select>

  <input class='all' type="text" name="price" placeholder='price' id="price" />
  <input class='all' type="text" name="min_price" placeholder='min_price' id="min_price" />
  <input class='all' type="text" name="max_price" placeholder='max_price' id="max_price" />


  <input class='all' type="text" name="fare" placeholder='fare' id="fare" />
  <input class='all' type="text" name="min_fare" placeholder='min_fare' id="min_fare" />
  <input class='all' type="text" name="max_fare" placeholder='max_fare' id="max_fare" />

</form>
```